# What is a good Subversion Client?

Tags: svn, client, versions, smartsvn

I use a subversion client called SmartSVN, but it needs Java in order to run. I would like to get rid of that dependency and try something new. Can you think of a better SVN client?

I have tried TortoiseSVN and RapidSVN and I did not like any of those. I do have Versions on the mac and I absolutely love that program. Is there anything even remotely similar to that on Windows? I do not mind paying money for it.

Comment: You're trying to remove Java as a dependency? Is there any particular reason for that? Just curious.

Comment: What didn't you like about tortoise SVN?

Comment: You named up the only 2 mature non-Java subversion clients for Windows

Comment: I just do not liking Java installed, I never liked the way it works.  Is SmartSVN the best GUI based client out there then?

Comment: TortoiseSVN digs way too deep into Windows.  I do not like seeing check marks on my Windows folders when I go through Windows.

Comment: While I agree to an extent about the TortoiseSVN shell integration, you should be able to disable the icon overlays on the folders through  the settings.

Comment: Wow. Back when I used Subversion (I've now switched to Git), Tortoise was the one piece of Windows software I missed on my Mac. I think the filesystem integration is largely a *good* thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not being a Mac user, I am not familiar with Versions.  In my experience, there is a really great SVN client called AnkhSVN.  It is a Visual Studio Plugin, so that probably eliminates it from consideration.

What features are you looking for in particular?

Comment: I am looking for primarily Visual Studio.  Are there any decent ones that I could buy?

Comment: @Nathan, [http://www.visualsvn.com/](VisualSVN) and [AnkhSvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) are the two best that I have seen.  I believe that Ankh is open source, VisualSVN is $49 for a single license.  VisualSvn has a demo version, so I suggest you try both and decide which one you like better.

Comment: Is SmartSVN the best GUI client available?

Comment: @Nathan, I have not found a stand-alone client I like better for subversion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [netbeans](http://netbeans.org) + svn plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be doing development in Visual Studio then [AnhkSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)
is a good plugin that works great with Subversion

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a GUI approach, you might want to take a look at [Vercue](http://www.vercue.com/); the GUI reminds me a bit of Versions.

The other option that many people choose is some kind of IDE integration -- nowadays I do most of my SVN stuff either within IntelliJ or from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the Collabnet subversion plugin for Eclipe and it seems to be quite good. There are a couple of things not quite right with it but it is pretty solid, eg I wish the version comparison is a bit more full featured.

What kind of features are you looking for, and do you want it to be integrated into an IDE?

In general, I use TortiseSVN or the commmand line client.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of client are you looking for? Are you trying to integrate with VisualStudio or Eclipse? I take it you're looking for a Windows client. If you are, you need to use the specific plugins for those environments.

You can take a look at the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients) comparing various Subversion clients. Almost all of them will allow for free trials of at least 30 days. Many are open source.

Answer (score -2):

The below site discuses various svn clients available for iMac and it's advantages and drawbacks.

[click here to visit](http://svn-ref.assembla.com/mac-svn-client-reviews.html)